# AWS Lambda: TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not StreamingBody

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda

I have a Lambda function that's used to read a gzip file and generate a sha512 hash value based on the content inside the file. The hash value will then be used to compare with the expected hash value to determine if the file has been manipulated. Previously, the code was written in the following way, which causes the function to run indefinitely if it encounters huge files:

```
import gzip
import hashlib
with gzip.open(csv_object["Body"], 'rb') as f:
    for l in f:
        content += l
print(hashlib.sha512(content).hexdigest())
```

Note: The csv_object["Body"] basically points to the file in our s3 bucket.

To solve the issue, I have written it in another way and have tested it first in my local IDE. The code is as below:

```
import hashlib
import gzip

sha512 = hashlib.sha512()
with gzip.open('test_file.csv.gz', 'rb') as file:
    sha512.update(file.read())
print(sha512.hexdigest())
```

From my IDE, the results can be printed out almost instantly, but when I pasted it over and run in lambda, it failed. We then found out that the issue is likely caused by placing csv_object["Body"] as the argument of gzip.open(). The error we got from CloudWatch was:

[ERROR] TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not StreamingBody

Have anyone encountered this?

Comment: try with `csv_object["Body"].read()`

Comment: Your code appears incomplete. Where is `csv_object` defined? Where is `content` defined?

Comment: @sytech I am just showing the hash gen logic of the code.. The csv_object was already declared earlier with boto3. content is also declared, with the purpose of loading the content line by line into it to generate its hash in the end.

Comment: @Marcin I am not sure if thats the issue since we have done file.read(). I have tested it out too and it threw an error that assume the content as the directory: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'' Traceback. The content appears to be b'' because its too large to handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both examples, you're attempting to load the entire file into memory.  This will create a hard limit on the file size that you can use in a Lambda, since by default they have fairly small memory allocations.

Rather than doing that, you can both decompress the object in a streaming fashion, and pass that stream to hashlib to calculate the hash, which will easily allow large files to be processed within a Lambda execution environment:

```python
import gzip
import hashlib
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
resp = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
# Pass the StreamingBody to gzip to decompress it as a stream
gz = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=resp['Body'])
# Read the file in small chunks to stream the results into hashlib
sha512 = hashlib.sha512()
while True:
    # Read 8 MiB at a time
    data = gz.read(8388608)
    if len(data) == 0:
        break
    sha512.update(data)
digest = sha512.hexdigest()

# -- or for Python 3.11 --

# And pass the decompressed stream to hashlib to hash it as a stream
digest = hashlib.file_digest(gz, 'sha512').hexdigest()
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!
Tried it and got this error:
[ERROR] AttributeError: module 'hashlib' has no attribute 'file_digest'

Thought it could be due to incompatible library version so I tweaked the last line to digest = hashlib.sha512(gz).hexdigest(). Then I got this: 
[ERROR] TypeError: object supporting the buffer API required Traceback (most recent call last)

Comment: @Kewei Likely you're running an older version of Python, I included logic demonstrating the same idea for older versions as well.